# Symfony how do you access form fields and pass to rendered forms?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form that has two rendered controllers (forms) inside it. I want to pass a variable from the main form to the rendered. I know I can do it with something like this:

```
{{ render(controller(
'CompanyNameofBundle:Search:shortjq', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}
```

But I am having troubles accessing the 'orgid' which is in the main form.

my.html.twig

```
{% extends 'CompanyNameofBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Organization Edit</h1>

    {{  form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}

    <div class="form-group'">
        <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_label(edit_form.orgName, 'Organization Name') }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_widget(edit_form.orgName) }}</div>


        <div class="hidden">{{ form_widget(edit_form.orgId) }}</div>


        <div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<ul class="record_actions">
    <li>{{ form_end(edit_form) }}</li>
    <li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('org') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

    {{ render(controller(
    'CompanyNameofBundle:Search:shortjq', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}


{% if entity.orgId is not null %}
    {{ render(controller(
        'CompanyNameofBundle:OrgMember:test', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

SearchController.php

```
/**
     * @Route("/shortjq", name="shortjq")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function shortjqAction()
    {
        $form   = $this->createForm(new JqueryType(), null, [
            'action' => '',
            'method' => 'POST'
        ]);
        return array(
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

JqueryType.php

```
/**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('orgid', 'integer')
            ->add('search', 'submit')
        ;

    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'companynameofbundle_jquery';
    }
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble in retrieving `orgId`? In the controller? In the template?

Comment: @shayster01 you must return entity in your controller to access it in template.

Comment: @D4V1D I am having trouble in the 'my.html.twig' getting the orgId from that file to the rendered controller form '{{ render(controller(
    'CompanyNameofBundle:Search:shortjq', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}'

Answer (score 0):

To access the form widgets into the views I use this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.orgid) }}
```

If you also want to add attributes to that widget you can add them like that (for example to add a class to the widget):

```
{{ form_widget(form.org, { 'attr': {'class': 'the-css-class-you-want'} }) }}
```

Here you can search for more information [Twig Template Form Function and Variable Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

Comment: I am clearly doing that above but trying to pass it to the '{{ render(controller(
    'CompanyNameofBundle:Search:shortjq', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}' is not working